# Show that $X$ is completely normal $\iff $ any two weakly separated sets can be strongly separated.

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is said to be completely normal if every subspace of it is normal.

Show that $X$ is completely normal $\iff $ any two weakly separated sets can be strongly separated.

Two sets $A,B$ are said to weakly separated if $A\cap \overline B=\overline A\cap B=\emptyset $

Two sets $A,B$ are said to strongly  separated if there exits open sets $U,V$ such that $A\subset U;B\subset V;U\cap V=\emptyset $

I could not do the reverse i.e if every subspace of $X$ is normal then $X$ is completely normal

Let $A,B$ be two sets in $X$ such that $\overline A_X\cap B=\overline B_X\cap A=\emptyset $

From here  I took $Y=X\setminus (\overline A_X\cap \overline B_X)$.Now $Y$ is normal and open.How to proceed now?

Please help

Comment: i have edited it @graydad

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that definition, but isn't the reverse of the problem still mistated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re on the right track. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $Y$, and their closures in $Y$ are disjoint:

$$(\operatorname{cl}_YA)\cap\operatorname{cl}_YB=(Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA)\cap(Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XB)=\varnothing\;.$$

Thus, there are disjoint sets $U$ and $V$, open in $Y$, such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$. But $Y$ is open in $X$, so $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$, and we’re done.

Comment: One problem :$cl_Y A\cap cl_YB=\emptyset\implies cl_Y A\subset U ;cl_YB\subset V$  but I have to do it for $A,B$ not their closures in $Y$

Comment: Why are $A,B$ subsets of $Y$ ? I have assumed them to be subsets of $X$..

Comment: @learnmore: That $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $Y$ follows from the way you defined $Y$. And of course $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_YA\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_YB\subseteq V$.

Comment: i am not getting why $A,B\subset Y$ please help

Comment: @learnmore: Suppose that $x\in A\setminus Y$. Then $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}B$, so $x\in A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$, which is impossible. The argument for $B$ is entirely similar.

Comment: thanks for the comments its now clear

Comment: @learnmore: You're welcome.